# E: Unable to locate package vim on Debian jessie simplified Docker container

Tags: debian, apt

From inside a Debian docker container running jessie I get

```
vi blah
bash: vi: command not found
```

so naturally I reach for my install command

```
sudo apt-get install vim

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vim
```

while searching for some traction I came across these suggestions with various outputs

```
        cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main

        apt-get install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common

        apt-get install python-software-properties
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-software-properties


        apt-get install apt-file
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apt-file
```

since this server is the docker container for a mongo image it intentionally is a bare bones Debian installation ... installing vi is just to play about during development

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I found this solution

```
apt-get update

apt-get install apt-file

apt-file update

apt-get install vim     # now finally this will work !!!
```

here is a copy N paste version of above

```
apt-get update && apt-get install apt-file -y && apt-file update && apt-get install vim -y
```

Alternative approach ... if you simply need to create a new file do this when no editor is available

```
cat > myfile
(use terminal to copy/paste)
^D
```

Comment: Perfect.. just followed these steps blindly.. it worked..

Comment: last line save my time thanks ... this is for second time ... that this answer helped me

Comment: This worked great for me.  All I had to do was `apt-get update` then `apt-get install ...`

Comment: I used that to install vim in a running docker container. Don't ask why :)

Answer (score 21):

Although [Scott Stensland](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10949/scott-stensland)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336393/232476) works, you don't need to install `software-properties-common` and `python-software-properties`. Running only the following commands is enough.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-get install vim
```

Comment: this one works for me..

Comment: this one works as well and don't install all the things that `software-properties-common` and `python-software-properties` will bring.

Comment: I get a `Unable to locate package apt-file` with this one :(

Comment: Small improvement for the second line try `apt-get install apt-file -y` to skip the y/n prompt, and also `apt-get install vim -y` for the fourth line.